# Does the Email Preference Center have presentation details to edit?

Tags: exm

I'm documenting an `EXM` setup for Sitecore 9.1 and would like to use the new Email Preference Center. The requirements for setting up a subscription page include the ability to list out certain products to subscribe/unsubscribe dynamically based on `xDB` custom `facet` information.

This wouldn't work for the out of the box categories as they change for each user continuously. I would like to inject a new rendering onto the provided page but I can't find any documentation that says if you can add renderings to the page.

Does anyone know how far the Email Preference Center page can be customized?

Answer (score 1):

You asked, 'Does the Email Preference Center have presentation details to edit?'.  It does not.  That page seems to be more of a bolt-on, that (I think) came from the original ECM module.  We had to figure out recently where all the content came from.  Here's what we found.

Subscription preferences page lives here. 
`/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/SubscriptionPreferences.ashx`

Here's what's *customizable* and where it lives.
[image]
1. Preference Center Layout Html: Lives in the preferences center section of the email root

2. Title lives in the same place
3. Logo & intro text live in the branding section of the email root
4. Marketing preferences are selected from within the marketing categories section of the email root.  Category groupings are managed in the email node of `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Marketing categories`
   5 & 7. Unsubscribe text & button text lives in the preferences center section of the email root
5. Brand name lives in the branding section of the email root

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

This is documented in the sitecore EXM help here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/91/email-experience-manager/en/configure-preference-center-options.html

Comment: Hi lynda, welcome to the site. Be aware that link-only answers are not preferred as URLs can move, links can become broken. Can you leave the link, but also quote the relevant piece for the question so that the answer is self-sufficient without the link?